# AWS MySql RDS: "Got error 28 from storage engine"

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, grails, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I’m working on a relatively small application, serving about 1,500 users and running on a Mysql database that is about 300 megs. The entire system runs on AWS with a single dedicated EC2 node running the Grails application on Tomcat 8 and a single dedicated Mysql RDS instance. The system has been running live in production for about three years with no database issues. The two largest tables contain about 40k records. The application is built using Grails and Java 1.7.

Yesterday our application began throwing the following exception, with the underlying error message of:

> "Got error 28 from storage engine"

The logs available from the RDS admin web console are empty.

Googling has not revealed any promising leads that have helped us resolve the issue, other than most messages point out that the disk is out of space. Given that most search results refer to disk space. Being software developers rather than DBA's with significant Mysql expertise, we boosted the storage space of the Mysql RDS instance. Unfortunately, today our application is still sporadically throwing the same exception. Having created our Mysql DRS instance with 15 gigs of space -- which is several orders of magnitude of additional space than our application makes use of -- we are at a lost as to what is the root cause of this issue. Our guess is that there is possibly some out of the box Mysql limitation that we are hitting up against but have no idea what it may be or how to solve it. Indeed, the whole reason we host onRDS was to avoid issues of this type.

Doing some Googling, this seems like a somewhat common Mysql error but that does not have any concrete trail for us to follow. Most suggestions talk about checking the filesystem or "inode" space. Given that this is a hosted Mysql RDS instance on AWS, I am unsure if or how to check such things. Looking at the CloudWatch for the RDS instance, I can see that the CPU is idle and that the instance is dramatically under the 15 gig storage limit.

Does anyone have any suggestions for us to investigate?

Given that we are new to RDS, can you please point us to any documentation or -- even better -- suggest what settings we can tweak in the RDS console -- to help prevent this error from occuring? Ideally, we moved to RDS thinking that if this was a mysql sizing or scaling issue that moving to RDS would solve the problem. As a last resort, this morning we then deleted about 20k rows of unessential data. Unfortunately, the issue persists and we continue to experience the issue.

A few questions:

1. Are there any RDS settings we can adjust to avoid this issue?
2. Can this be solved by moving to a larger RDS instance, perhaps with more memory?
3. Would we experience this issue if we moved to Aurora?

Comment: What is your total RDS Disc space and how much is available?

Comment: I should have added that I am using a db.t2.small instance, that the cpu is at 0.83, the memory is at 930 MB, and storage says 13,900 MB., and the DB engine version is the default 5.6.27. To answer your question, how can I determine my total RDS Disc space available?

Comment: Error 28 is literally "No space left on device."  Are you familiar with `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;`? `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`?  You may have a runaway Cartesian query that builds up a massive temp table, which then immediately goes away and frees the space again each time it finishes.  Strange to have nothing in the error log but you may want to verify that `LOG_WARNINGS` is set to 2 in your parameter group.

Answer (score 0):

Well from your comment this is definitely a low on storage issue. Because 13 Gb is very less storage. you can check the free available storage in the dashboard. Check this screenshot below in the "Storage" metric under monitoring if it goes ahead of the red line you will start getting Error 28. You will have to increase the storage of your RDS instance or free up some space. I will suggest increase the storage to avoid this issue in future.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I have checked my console and the storage is no where near the red line. Given that my instance is sized to 15 gigs and it is displaying the number 13,900 -- just as your storage shows 64,000 in your pic -- I assume that means how much storage I have available and free (I know that my database is about 200-300 megs). Do you have any other suggestions that may be causing the "Got error 28 from storage engine" error?

Comment: Error 28 is definitely a storage issue. Do one thing take a snapshot of your current DB launch a new DB with that snapshot with increase storage and point your application to go to the new DB and see if you get the Error 28. test it out.

Comment: After working with AWS tech support, they agree that the database itself is not out of storage. My next step, as you suggest, was to create a larger instance (I went with a t2.large with 50 gigs of storage) to see if the problem remained. And it unfortunately does still occur. After much other trying/troubleshooting I saw a table that had ~40k rows of longtext data, each several kilo in size. After deleting all that data and restarting mysql, we are then unable to reproduce the issue. To me this indicates some type of sizing limitation that we am missing and not aware of. Any ideas?

Comment: I should add that what pointed us on toward this large table was the realization that in our log from our application contained this message: Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The table 'table_name' is full

Comment: I will suggest start monitoring that table.